# C# and SQL parameters to prevent injections

Tags: c#, .net, sql, data-access-layer, sqlparameter

I am wondering how (in my code below), that I make sure that dataID is a text (or varchar or int) in the parameter passing below?

```
public T ExecuteQuery<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> getResult, string query, params IDataParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.DefaultConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // Declare the parameter in the query string
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }

                command.Prepare();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return getResult(dr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetMySpecId(string dataId)
    {
        return ExecuteQuery(
            dr =>
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    return dr[0].ToString();
                }

                return string.Empty;
            },
            "select specId from MyTable where dataId = @dataId",
            new SqlParameter("dataId", dataId));
    }
```

I am used to code like so:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("key", SqlDbType.Text));

command.Prepare();

command.Parameters[0].Value = dataId;
```

How else in the code at the top, do I pass two or more parameters into the ExecuteQuery?

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteQuery` already takes multiple parameters. It is a `ParamArray` which means it takes any number of parameters and turns them into an array.

For example, if I have a function like this:

```
public int Sum(params int[] numbersToSum) { ... }
```

I can call it like this:

```
Sum(1, 2, 5, 6, 1)
```

In your case you can call it this way:

```
ExecuteQuery(
   dr => { //snip }, 
   query,
   new SqlParameter("dataId", dataId),
   new SqlParameter("anotherParm", parm2),
   new SqlParameter("anotherParm", parm3),
   ... );
```

Comment: how do i make it so the type is passed too, like SqlDBType.NVarchar?

Comment: Assuming you're using the the `SqlParameter` class in `System.Data.SqlClient`, that's something that you can set on the `SqlParameter` objects you are passing (the `SqlDBType` property). However, the `SqlDBType` is inferred from the .NET object given in the constructor so you don't really need to specify it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The code is using the [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword, so it seems that you should just write additional escaped SQL and keep appending the parameters to the end of the method. Here is an example using your code as a base.

The link provides a fuller explanation, but `params` makes it so that you can have a variable number of parameters (as long as they are the same type) at the end of a method signature. It puts all of the final parameters that fall in this `params` variable into an array.

```
 return ExecuteQuery(
        dr =>
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                return dr[0].ToString();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        },
        "select specId from MyTable where dataId = @dataId and somethingelse = @else",
        new SqlParameter("dataId", dataId), 
        new SqlParameter("else", elseVar);
```

Comment: what is they are of different types?

Comment: i would also want to pass different types, maybe I should change it to a dictionary?